# How to get Solr Suggester to return spelling suggestions as well

Tags: apache, solr, autosuggest

I'm currently integrating Apache Solr searching into my platform and using the Suggester functionality for autocompletion. However, the Suggester module does not return spelling suggestions as well, so for example if I search for:

```
shi
```

The suggester module returns among others the following:

```
shirt
shirts
```

However, if I search for:

```
shrt
```

No suggestions are returned. What I'd like to know is:

a) Is it incorrect configuration of the Suggester module that has resulted in this?
b) Is the Suggester module built in such a way that it does not return spelling suggestions?
c) How can I get the Suggester module to return spelling suggestions as well without having to make a second request for spelling correction suggestions?

I have read the Solr documentation but cannot seem to make a headway with this.

Comment: did you find any solution?!

Comment: @HesamKashefi I didn't find a solution unfortunately. In the end I decided not to use the Suggester module and took a different approach. Since then I've switched to elasticsearch and never looked back!

Comment: So does elasticserach support this kind of suggests? Is it better than Solr?

Comment: @HesamKashefi Elasticsearch does support these kinds of suggestions and much much more. In terms of whether it is better than Solr, I think they are both useful tools, it's really about which one is more suitable for your situation. I chose to switch to Elasticsearch for the following reasons: a) I found it easier to work with b) I realised better performance gains c) It offered extra functionality that I needed d) It supported distributed architecture out-of-the-box

Answer (score 11):

You need to configure a spell check component to generate alternate spelling options as described at https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/spell-checking.html

The task consists of following steps:

First, update the `schema.xml` with a spellcheck field. This often means creating a new field and copying multiple fields to a single `spellcheck` field:

```
<field name="spellcheck" type="text_general" 
   indexed="true" 
   stored="false" 
   multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="id" dest="spellcheck"/>
<copyField source="name" dest="spellcheck"/>
<copyField source="description" dest="spellcheck"/>
<copyField source="longdescription" dest="spellcheck"/>
<copyField source="category" dest="spellcheck"/>
<copyField source="source" dest="spellcheck"/>
<copyField source="merchant" dest="spellcheck"/>
<copyField source="contact" dest="spellcheck"/>
```

In `solrconfig.xml` update your request handler and create a `solr.SpellCheckComponent` and add it to your search handler.

```
    <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
      <lst name="spellchecker">
        <!-- decide between dictionary based vs index based spelling suggestions, 
        in most cases it makes sense to use index based spell checker
        as it only generates terms which are 
        actually present in your search corpus -->
        <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
        <!-- field to use -->
        <str name="field">spellcheck</str>
        <!-- buildOnCommit|buildOnOptimize -->
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
        <!-- $solr.solr.home/data/spellchecker-->
        <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
        <str name="accuracy">0.7</str>
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.0001</float>
      </lst>
    </searchComponent>

    <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <int name="rows">10</int>
        <str name="df">defaultSearchField</str>
        <!-- spell check component configuration -->
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
      </lst>
      <!-- add spell check processing after 
        the default search component. This is 
        the search component name. -->
      <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
      </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

- Reindex the corpus
- Test suggestions are working. For example,

http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=coachin

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 12,
    "params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "coachin"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  },
  "spellcheck": {
    "suggestions": [
      "coachin", {
        "numFound": 1,
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 7,
        "suggestion": ["cochin"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have previously used the spellcheck component on its own, however if results are found for the search query, the spellcheck component does not return any suggestions, hence why I decided to use the Suggester component. For example, if I have results for the search term "sheet", I would still expect to see a suggestion "sheeting" if my spelling field contains that possibility.

Comment: Hi Dude.. @Nitin Tripathi
for me up to here working fine but my question is... please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196793/how-get-suggestions-from-solr-server-in-a-php-variable