# How to get Solr suggester work on misspellings too?

Tags: search, solr, autosuggest

I'm implementing a small web search engine with solr and I'm making use of the Suggester component
to provide autocomplete functionality in the query form.

I am able to get suggestions from solr but I'd like to have misspellings corrected too.
What I'm asking is the same as [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047119/how-to-get-solr-suggester-to-return-spelling-suggestions-as-well)
but I'm using a different configuration of the handlers (I'm submitting partial queries to a separate /suggest request handler, before submitting my final query to /select).

from **SolrConfig.xml**:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">suggest</str>
<!--  <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str> -->
  <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory</str>
  <str name="field">spelling</str>  <!-- all the other fields are copied here -->
  <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
  <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
</lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="suggest">true</str>
  <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
  <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
  <!-- <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str> -->
  <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>      
</lst>
<arr name="components">
  <str>suggest</str>
 <!-- <str>spellcheck</str> enabling this gives me error: dictionary not found: suggest (same for "default")-->
</arr>
</requestHandler>`
```

changing the classname of the suggester component to directSolrSpellChecker gives me spell checking but not suggestions.

how can I get the suggester operate on spelling corrections as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try using thsi:

```
<!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">default</str>
  <str name="field">spelling</str>
  <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
  <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
  <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
  <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
  <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
  <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
  <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
  <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
  <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
  <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
  <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
  <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
  <int name="minQueryLength">2</int>
  <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
  <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
  <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents
    <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
  -->
</lst>
```

```
  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="df">spelling</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
  <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
  <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
  <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
  <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>         
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
  <str>spellcheck</str>
</arr>
```